# Pushdown Automata definition

Tags: automata

I am quite confused about formal description of PDA (push down automata)

If we write down L(M), this means that PDA M recognizes language L, correct ?

then , L(M)* means that PDA M recognizes that L* right ?

but what is the L* means ? how PDA can recognize infinite combination of L  ?

Comment: Please be careful with the terms you use. WHat do you mean by _infinite combination_?

Answer (score 2):

> L(M)* means that PDA M recognizes that L* right ?

No! It means a language which is constituted from the concatenation of any number of sentences (including zero) that are valid in the language recognized by the PDA M.

Given that L(M) is context-free, it is easy to prove that L(M)* is context-free too.

To construct L(M)* , just take all the grammar of L(M), take the starting symbol S from L(M) and add two new productions `R -> S R` and `R -> empty` where R is the starting symbol of L(M)*.

So, given that L(M)* is context-free, then there is some PDA that recognize it. If you could construct a PDA for L(M), then a PDA for L(M)* should be trivial to construct, given that it is almost the same as L(M) just with two extra productions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, what do you mean "one extra production" ?

Comment: In fact are two extra productions (I fixed the answer for that). These extra productions are `R -> S R` and `R -> empty`.

Comment: Why not just use `S -> S S`?

Comment: Hm ... can PDA state have 2 ways to go ?

Comment: @Lincoded You could use `S -> S S` AND `S -> empty`, but I prefered to introduce a new symbol to keep the L(M) subgrammar of L(M)* unchanged and unafected.